# Are c++ bits switched atomically when reading unsigned ints across a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

In C++ on a mac, pc and unix:
If I am writing to unsigned ints or Ipp32us on one thread (the write thread) and reading the unsigned ints from another (the read thread), does the read thread read without glitches, even if the write thread is writing.  I am wanting to know if the bits are switched atomically.
Thank you

Comment: C++ has standard atomic types if you need to guarantee that behavior.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour to have unsequenced read and write unless the type is atomic

Answer (score 3):

By the standard, for non-atomic types, there are no guarantees. In practice, it usually depends on the underlying hardware and the alignment of the data type in question; for example, if 64 bit writes are implemented on the hardware as a pair of 32 bit writes, then you can see torn values (half the old value, half the new). If the hardware implements them as a true 64 bit write, you're probably safe, but it's not something to count on.

Keep in mind, the "write" may be torn at multiple stages, e.g. the compiler might actually generate separate move to memory instructions for each half (so even on a single core, another thread could be scheduled between halves of the write), or it might write it as a single instruction, but the processor implements it internally as a pair of writes (in either order, with even the assembly not telling you the order; architectures like x86 appear to execute CISC instructions, but actually translate them to a completely different internal RISC instruction set), or the processor might implement it as a single write, but if the storage spans a cache line and the system has [weak memory ordering](https://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/), it could easily have flushed only one of the lines (unpredictably) by the time some other processor requests it, etc.

Point is, if you want atomic writes and reads, actually use [C++11 `std::atomic` types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic). Without it, even if it works, that just means it works on that compiler, with that hardware, and says nothing at all about portability.

Comment: Thanks for that info.  I don’t mind if the values are torn any which way, as long as they are valid ints.

Comment: @ddd, Re, "I don’t mind if the values are torn any which way." In other words, the value in the variable is not important. In that case, why have a variable at all?

Comment: @SolomonSlow: Exactly my thought. If it's okay to read a value that literally never existed as a single coherent value *ever* in the program (e.g. as a 32 bit example torn on 16 bits, the writer thread alternately writes `0xDEAD0000` and `0x0000BEEF`, but the reader could also see `0x00000000` or `0xDEADBEEF`, neither of which were ever written there), then you're entering a realm of madness; may as well just execute an x86-64 RDRAND instruction and get random bytes off the processor.

Comment: It is for a spectrum analyzer.  I am experimenting with alternatives to thread locks.  The peak value will be stored in the read thread.  If values are slightly misrepresented by a torn value in the UI for an instant that may be ok.

Comment: @ddd: Well, in that case you have other issues. Without `volatile` or atomics involved, the compiler is free to output assembly that reads the value once and never again. After all, the thread reading never writes to it, so clearly the value can never change; it would be undefined behavior to change it from another thread or asynchronously via signals w/o `volatile`/atomics, so the compiler can safely *assume* no undefined behavior and cache the value to a register once and never read it again. Even if it does read it, with a weak memory model, the hardware could effectively do the same thing.

Comment: @ddd: That's one of the big problems with undefined behavior. The compiler can and does assume it never occurs, and can output code that relies on that assumption. `if (valuetotest) { codepath1; } else { code path with undefined behavior; }` can compile to just `codepath1`, without ever testing `valuetotest`, because clearly it can never be false or you'd hit undefined behavior. Values can be cached because changing them would be undefined behavior. It's not just "does what I told it, but gets bad results", it's "doesn't do what I told it, because I told it to do undefined things".

Comment: Thanks for those two responses.  That has given me plenty to ponder.  You guys are fantastic.  I am about to enrol in an online Computer science Uni degree as a little side hobby.  There are too many holes in my knowledge.